# Access string.xml Resource File from Java Android Code

Tags: java, android, string

How do you access the values in the `res/values/string.xml` resource file from the Android `Activity class`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Put this code in `res/values/string.xml`

```
<string-array name="planet"> 
    <item>Mercury</item>
    <item>Venus</item>
    <item>Earth</item>
    <item>Mars</item>
</string-array>
```

This code to be placed in `res/layout/main.xml` and remove default widgets present in `main.xml`.

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/planet"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:entries="@array/planet"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 152):

Well you can get String using,

```
getString(R.string.app_name);
```

And, you can get string-array using

```
String arr[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planet);
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),arr[i], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
}
```

Comment: <string-array name="planet"><item>Mercury</item><item>Venus</item>
<item>Earth</item></string-array> for this code while i use getString(R.string.planets);

Comment: I checked your answer but I got ForceClose error.  Thanks for helping

Comment: THIS IS LOGCAT  08-27 20:16:04.844: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-27 20:16:04.844: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.string/com.string.string}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f050000

Comment: THIS IS LOGCAT
08-27 20:16:04.844: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-27 20:16:04.844: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.string/com.string.string}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f050000
08-27 20:16:04.844: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)

Comment: This is LogCat information.08-27 22:17:20.980: INFO/AndroidRuntime(299): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed.I used your updated code but stringArray is not displaying on Emulator

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got required output in LogCat but how to get same output on Emulator.

Comment: Thanks its working fine but i need to display array at a time.

Comment: It means, as i used above code it displaying as Mercury wait for second then venus wait for second and then Earth.But i need it to be displayed as Mercury Venus Earth simultaniously.

Comment: See code that I entered and try it. Following code shows my requirement. Thanks you tried to solve my problem.

Comment: Note that getString() is not static. If you want to assign a string.xml value to a static property of your app class, do it in you class onCreate().

Answer (score 46):

strings.xml:

```
<string name="some_text">Some Text</string>
```

Activity:

```
getString(R.string.some_text);
```

Comment: @MByD That's the first tim I was faster then you =)

Comment: <string-array name="planet">
    <item>Mercury</item>
    <item>Venus</item>
    <item>Earth</item></string-array>

Answer (score 15):

If getString(R.string.app_name); isn't working for you, you can pass context like this:

```
context.getString(R.string.app_name);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have the context of Activity, go with:

```
getString(R.string.app_name);
```

If you don't have the context, try below, you can get the context from activity using `Constructor`.

```
mContext.getString(R.string.app_name);
```