# android multilingual strings in POJO class

Tags: java, android, multilingual, android-resources

My application is a basic notepad style application where the main activity is a list and each item can be edited. The data for each item includes the name of the item and then a list of text fields. I currently have a class to manage the items as follows:

```
public class Item implements Serializeable {
  private String name;
  private String review;
  public Item() {
    name = Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.name_movie);
    description = Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.description_like);
 }
  public Item(String itemname, String itemreview) {
//... followed by getters and setters
}
```

then in <strings.xml>

```
<string name="name_movie">movie</string>
<string name="name_movie">book</string>
<string name="name_movie">record</string>
<string name="description_like">good</string>
<string name="description_love">great</string>
```

etc. The are all translated into other languages and I can refer to them in code as

```
R.string.name_movie
R.string.description_like
```

etc. I'm summarizing because you get the idea.

The problem is the default constructor where I'd like to assign values based on string resources. Unfortunately, to get system resources requires a context. These are POJO classes and have no context. Additionally, I the main activity holds an arraylist of items into a file so I've made the items serializeable. Because there are serializeable I need a no argument constructor so I can't use a static member variable for the context with a constructor such as follows:

```
    public Item(Context context) {
      m_context = context;
    }
```

My question is **in an android application what is the best way to access multilingual strings in a plain old java object that is serializeable?** I'm reviewed the following discussions, among others:  [getString Outside of a Context or Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253328/getstring-outside-of-a-context-or-activity), [Access string.xml Resource File from Java Android Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7213924/access-string-xml-resource-file-from-java-android-code), and [Static way to get 'Context' in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002288/static-way-to-get-context-in-android).

What other ways are there that I could use localized strings in these objects? I considered storing the resource identifier instead of the string in my item but I want to leave it open to modify my application to take user entered strings rather than just picking from a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Application class.
Extend Android Application class, add a static variable Context and onCreate Method assign application context to it.
Add a method get contact Wich return your application context.
And inside your pojo, you can have access it by Application.MyMethod() and so.
( Don't forget to assign your application class to your manifest.

Comment: For some reason I suspected this would be problematic for having a static reference to the context. This post has more information https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018545/getapplication-vs-getapplicationcontext. However, this seems to work well in my app.
Thank you!

Comment: For what i know, I never had any problem with this. No leak or so. I use Application mainly to have an access point to my Singleton. Instead of declaration some static member here and there and so lost track of them if you have a big custom lib. I almost never use static member but when I need static access to a Singleton, I store them in my application extend. I think that one of the way to use Application...

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to have singleton class as Teddy Smith suggested and then in my translations I have a string for each language. For example,

```
 <string name="language">en</string>
```

Then in translations editor I have the language string defined as sp for Spanish, etc. then when I get the value of the string resource "language" and can determine in which language my app is running.

The purpose of this is to have a multilingual audio prompting application with a defined list of audio prompts specific to the user's language.

thanks for the help